# textView.setText is not working in compound view

Tags: android, java

`textView.setText` is not working properly in a compound view.
Means Both hello and jack are appearing...
and jack is displayed below layout not appearing if I put some background color,...
Could  somebody help... Thanks and regards...

Here is my code...

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:id="@+id/chatLayout"
             android:layout_width="300dp"
             android:layout_height="400dp"
             >

             <TextView 
                 android:id="@+id/chatNamed"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Hello"
                 android:textColor="#ffffff"
                 android:textSize="20dp"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                 />


         </RelativeLayout>
```

**CompoundView.java**

```
public class ChatCompoundView extends RelativeLayout {

    private static TextView zoneName;



    public ChatCompoundView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        setView();

    }
    public ChatCompoundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         this(context, attrs, 0);
         setView();

    }
    public ChatCompoundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
         super(context, attrs, defStyle);
           setView();
    }


    public void setView()
    {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.chat_layout, this);
        zoneName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatNamed);
    }
        zoneName.setText("jack");

    }
```

Comment: `zoneName.setText("jack");` is out of method , you put that line after "}" move that in method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah Now I got the Answer... Actually my constructors are called with this(context),.. and I need to call super(context)...

```
Code Changed to
public ChatCompoundView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setView();

    }
    public ChatCompoundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
         setView();

    }
    public ChatCompoundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
         super(context, attrs, defStyle);
           setView();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
LayoutInflater mInflater;
public ChatCompoundView (Context context) {
    super(context);
     mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
     setView();

}
```

**setView():**

```
public void setView(){
       mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, this, true);
       TextView zoneName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatNamed);
       zoneName .setText("jack");
}
```

Comment: Not Working means zoneName.setText("jack"); is setting the text but it's covered by the style of the relative layout... And the text is not appearing if background color is given

Comment: Actually its a relative layout and I've to put some more views in that relative layout... Thats why i can't make it as textview extention.